# Evaluate if the formula in a cell contains a character

Tags: excel-formula

How do I search a cell for specific text in its formula(not the cell output) using Excel 2010.  For example…I need to know if the highlighted cell has a “/” in the formula.

[image]

In this case the answer would be "No" or "False"

I have tried a few different options that all seem to search the cell output for the character instead of the cell formula.  Here is what I have tried that does not work:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",A1))

=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","") <> A1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of Excell (> 2010) you can use the function [FORMULATEXT](https://support.office.com/en-ie/Article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) like here:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",FORMULATEXT(A1)))
```

Otherwise you can replace that with a VBA function:

```
Function FormulaText(mycell As Range)
    FormulaText = mycell.Formula
End Function
```

Comment: I am using 2010, so FORMULATEXT() is out.
The VBA does work, but am wanting to do it with a formula in this case